# Where can I find the Chinese Canon Agama in English translation?

Tags: texts

Where can I find the Chinese Canon Agamas in English translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dirgha Agama

Thanks to [the reference contributed by ChrisW](https://sujato.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/on-the-dirgha-agama/), I was able to find the following fragments:

- [DA 11, DA 12, and DA 30](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/three-da.pdf) translated by bhikkhu Analayo
- [DA 21](https://suttacentral.net/en/da21) translated by Fan Dong Jing

The entire DA is available in print from BDK America (thanks for the link, Suminda Sirinath S. Dharmasena):

- http://www.bdkamerica.org/catalog/indian-sources

### Madhyama Agama

Online I was able to find the following sutras, translated by Charles D. Patton:

- [MA 1](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma1)
- [MA 2](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma2)
- [MA 10](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma10)
- [MA 11](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma11)
- [MA 17](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma17)
- [MA 42](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma42)
- [MA 45](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma45)
- [MA 51](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma51)
- [MA 186](https://suttacentral.net/en/ma186)

There is also this BDK America version, containing the first 71 sutras:

- [MA 1-71](http://www.bdkamerica.org/system/files/pdf/dBET_T0026_MadhyamaAgama1_2013_0.pdf)

### Samyukta Agama

According to the sutra commentaries in the Yogacara-bhumi Shastra, the Samyukta Agama was the earliest agama collection.

Turns out there are two version of Samyukta Agama, the long one (~1350 sutras), known by the scholars as T.99 or "ZA" and the short one (364 sutras), known as T.100 or "BZA". Most of the BZA is available in English translation by Marcus Bingenheimer either [online](http://buddhistinformatics.chibs.edu.tw/BZA/bzaComCatWebOrig.html) or in [one PDF](http://mbingenheimer.net/publications/bingenheimer_StudiesInAgamaLit_2011.pdf). Most of the BZA sutras have almost identical counterparts in ZA.

Out of ~1350 sutras in the long Samyukta Agama, ~260 are available online so far, [most translated to English by bhikkhu Analayo](http://agamaresearch.ddbc.edu.tw/sa%E1%B9%83yukta-agama-3) and some by an unknown translator at [lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka](http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka) as well as by Choong Mun-keat:

- [SA1-32](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/translations/sa01.pdf)
- [SA33-58](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/translations/sa04.pdf)
- [SA59-87](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/translations/sa03.pdf)
- [SA103-110](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/translations/sa05.pdf)
- [SA111-138](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/sa06.pdf)
- [SA139-187](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/sa07.pdf)
- [SA188-229](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/sa08.pdf)
- [SA 232](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa232)
- [SA 236](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa236)
- [SA 249](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa249)
- [SA256-272](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/pdf/5-personen/analayo/translations/sa02.pdf)
- [SA 273](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa273)
- [T.100.6](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa-2.6) / SA 275
- (SĀ 276) “Attitudes Towards Nuns – A Case Study of the Nandakovāda in the Light of its Parallels”, (with an appendix by Giuliana Martini), Journal of Buddhist Ethics, 2010, vol. 17 pp. 332–400.  [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814020050/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/AttitudesTowardsNuns.pdf)
- [SA 287](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa287)
- [SA 293](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa293)
- [SA 296](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa296)
- [SA 297](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa297)
- [SA 299](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa299)
- [SA 300](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa300)
- SA 301: [Kātyāyana Gotra](http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099_LL_0301_katyayana)
- [SA 335](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa335)
- (SĀ 344 and SA 389) ” Right View and the Scheme of the Four Truths in Early Budhism, The Saṃyukta-āgama Parallel to the Sammādiṭṭhi-sutta and the Simile of the Four Skills of a Physician”, Canadian Journal of Bud­dhist Studies, 2011, vol. 7 pp. 11–44.  [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814022524/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/RightView.pdf)
- SA 371: [The Nutriments](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0371-nutriments)
- SA 374. [The Nutriments](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0374-nutriments)
- SA 379: [Turning the Dharma Wheel](http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099_LL_0379_dharma_wheel)
- SA 383. [Having Known](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0383-having-known)
- SA 451. [The Realms](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0451-realms)
- SA 474: [Gradual Subsiding](http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099_LL_0474_gradual_subsiding)
- (SĀ 505) “Śakra and the Destruction of Craving – A Case Study in the Role of Śakra in Early Buddhism”, Indian International Journal of Buddhist Studies, 2011, vol. 12 pp. 157-176.  [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210041409/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/SakraDestructionCraving.pdf)
- SA 606. [Bases of Mindfulness](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0606-smrtyupasthana)
- SA 610. [Correct Mindfulness](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0610-mindfulness)
- SA 615. [Bhikṣuṇī Residence](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0615-bhiksuni)
- (SĀ 619) “Protecting Oneself and Others Through Mindfulness – The Acrobat Simile in the Saṃyukta-āgama”, Sri Lanka International Journal of Buddhist Studies, 2012, vol. 2 pp. 1–23.   [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210113228/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/Protecting.pdf)
- SA 620. [The Monkey](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0620-monkey)
- SA 621. [The Young Bhikṣus](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0621-young-bhiksus)
- SA 623. [The World Beauty](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0623-world-beauty)
- SA 746. [Ānāpānasmṛti](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0746-anapanasmrti)
- SA 801: [Five Dharmas](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0801-five-dharmas)
- SA 802. [Knowledge](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0802-knowledge)
- SA 803. [Knowledge](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0803-knowledge)
- SA 804. [Cutting Off Thoughts](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0804-cutting-off-thoughts)
- SA 805. [Ariṣṭa](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0805-arista)
- SA 806. [Kapphiṇa](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0806-kapphina)
- SA 807. [Two Months](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0807-two-months)
- SA 808. [Kapilavastu](https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/T0099-LL-0808-kapilavastu)
- (SĀ 1042) “The Saṃyukta-āgama Parallel to the Sāleyyaka-sutta”, Journal of Buddhist Ethics, 2006, vol. 13 pp. 1–22.  [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210113401/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/SamyuktaAgamaSaleyyaka.pdf)
- [T.100 equivalents of SA 1062-1225](https://suttacentral.net/sa-2)
- (SĀ 1249) “Exemplary Qualities of a Monastic – The Saṃyukta-āgama Counterpart to the Mahāgopālaka-sutta and the Need of Balancing Inner Development with Concern for Others”, Sri Lanka International Journal of Buddhist Studies, 2010, vol. 1 pp. 1–22.  [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210113218/http://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/pdf/analayo/ExemplaryQualities.pdf)

### Ekottarika Agama

Unless otherwise noted, translated by Dr. Thich Huyen-Vi and Bhikkhu Pas­ad­ika in collaboration with Sara Boin-Webb, for the Buddhist Stud­ies Review.

- [EA 12.1](https://suttacentral.net/en/ea12.1) translated by Thích Nhất Hạnh, Annabel Laity
- EA 17.1 — [Mindfulness of Breathing](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-17-1/)
- EA 18.4 — [Brahmin](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-18-4/)
- EA 18.5 — [Elephant](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-18-5/)
- EA 18.8 — [Broad-minded](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-18-8/)
- EA 18.9 — [Authentic](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-18-9/)
- EA 18.10 — [Praise](http://santifm.org/santipada/2010/ekottara-agama-18-10/)
- [EA 19.2 - EA 19.11](https://suttacentral.net/ea19)
- [EA 20.1 - EA 20.13](https://suttacentral.net/ea20)
- [EA 21.1 - EA 21.10](https://suttacentral.net/ea21)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19743/254), which says that Bikkhu Sujato posted, "[Chinese Agama texts are now on SuttaCentral](https://sujato.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/chinese-agama-texts-are-now-on-suttacentral/)" -- on Sutta Central [starting here](https://suttacentral.net/sa1-100). Their being online even in Chinese may mean you can use dictionary/translation tools.

Comment: Most of the links are dead, unfortunately. :( Anyone have updated links?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this finds you in good health and peace of mind.

Just to let you know that this sentence:
"and some (10 SA texts and 1 EA text) by an unknown translator at lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka"
were my translations for my BA in Buddhist Studies at the University of Queensland, which I completed in 2004, under the supervision of Dr Rod Bucknell.

I intend to let that website know also.

best wishes
Joe
(Norman Joseph Smith)

Answer (score 0):

Tripitaka (Chinese to English):

Dirgha Agama:

1. The Canonical Book of the Buddha's Lengthy Discourses, Volume 1 (Bdk English Tripitaka)The Canonical Book of the Buddha's Lengthy Discourses, Volume 1 (Bdk English Tripitaka) by Shohei Ichimura.
2. The Canonical Book of the Buddha's Lengthy Discourses, Volume 2 (Bdk English Tripitaka: Taisho Volume 1, Number 1)The Canonical Book of the Buddha's Lengthy Discourses, Volume 2 (Bdk English Tripitaka: by Shohei Ichimura.
3. The Canonical Book of the Buddha’s Lengthy Discourses, Volume 3 (Bdk English Tripitaka, 1-1)The Canonical Book of the Buddha’s Lengthy Discourses, Volume 3 (Bdk English Tripitaka,by Shohei Ichimura.

Madhyama Agama:

1. The Madhyama Agama: Middle-length Discourses: 1 (BDK English Tripitaka) Hardcover – September 30, 2013 by Bhikkhu Analayo (Editor), Marcus Bingenheimer  (Editor), Rodney S. Bucknell (Editor).
2. The Madhyama Agama (Middle-Length Discourses) Volume II (Bdk English Tripitaka, 2) Hardcover – July 29, 2020 by Bhikkhu Analayo and Roderick S. Bucknell (Author).

Comment: These are very nice. Dirgha Agama and Madhyama Agama