# Websites with the Chinese canon translated into English?

Tags: sutras, texts, chinese-canon

Are there any websites that have an English translation of the Chinese Buddhist canon, similar to what is available for the Pali canon at [accesstoinsight.org](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/) and [suttacentral.net](https://suttacentral.net/)?

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: I'm curious why you look for the Chinese cannon instead of the pali cannon.

Comment: @RavindranathAkila Thank you for asking, i'm interested because i would like to study a couple of Sutras that are important to me and see how they compare with the "versions" in the Pali canon

Comment: Hope you find your answer. And may you realize the four noble truths!

Answer (score 2):

The following might be of some value:

- http://www.bdk.or.jp/english/english_tripitaka/publication_project.html and / or http://www.bdkamerica.org/blog/free-pdf-versions-many-volumes-bdk-english
- http://84000.co/ - this is from Tibetan sources
- http://lapislazulitexts.com/ (http://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka)

Answer (score 2):

That is or was difficult.

Other people have tried what you are trying to do (i.e. compare sutras with the Pali versions). To find whatever work they have already done, you might search for papers about the specific named Sutras.

In his book *A History of Mindfulness* in 2005, Bikkhu Sujato (who compares Nikayas with Agamas) wrote,

> The translations are from various
>   sources. Research was carried out in many places​—​monasteries, libraries,
>   Buddhist centres, internet​—​and I am not able to standardize or to check
>   all the references.

However, see [Chinese Agama texts are now on SuttaCentral](https://sujato.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/chinese-agama-texts-are-now-on-suttacentral/) posted in 2014.